# Can I add a horizontal navigation panel in the chatbot

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

My chatbot returns text from search engines results on the chatbot screen with the link in the form of a list. 
I want to add a horizontal navigation button suc that at once only 1 text result is shown for a query and the next result can be seen by clicking the next botton which will slide over the current result.

Can this be achieved via conversation>

Answer (score 2):

Conversation is one REST API endpoint, so you can calling the Watson conversation service, and built your application with custom code.

Take a look in this project: [conversation-simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple). One example using Watson Conversation with Node.js (Back-end). You can simple download this project and make your custom design (like [buttons](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/issues/65)) in the front-end or add more business roles in the back-end. Or, you can add your HTML custom code in the conversation and will `render` for you.

But, like I said, you need to build one custom code to added this painel in the [Front-end](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/tree/master/public) (HTML, CSS, Javascript). I recommend take a look `jQuery`, `bootstrap`, or search *templates*.

- See the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/) for using Watson Conversation.
- See the Official documentation for using this API.